# How to get DataSource file on client from "java.sql.ResultSet" on server?

Tags: mysql, gwt, datasource

How to get DataSource file on client from "java.sql.ResultSet"  on server?
My server code can get data from MYSQL.And I want to show the data to ListGrid on the client.
I want to use DataSource type to add the data to ListGrid .How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use sql on client side. GWT does not implement any sql (Result, DataSource, SQLException etc.). Simply put your results in a serialized class containing java primitives. You can ofcourse have a look at SmartGWT or SmartClient but you will have to pay for that [SmartGWT DataSource](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/DataSource.html).